# how to write non-zero expression for annotation in meta data for wcf ria service?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have a entity property like:

```
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

then validation can be added in metadata class like:

```
[Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount is required")]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

How are about for non-zero request?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a custom validation attribute.  Example:

```
class MyObject {
    [NonZero]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class NonZeroAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} must be non-zero", name);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var zero = Convert.ChangeType(0, value.GetType());
        return !zero.Equals(value);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (IsValid(value))
            return new ValidationResult(null);
        else
            return new ValidationResult(
                FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.MemberName)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `IsValid` return `null` as validation result when the value is valid?

Comment: @RobertSirre I don't see that anywhere in the documentation, so if you have a source then please let me know.  Having just reviewed the docs for `ValidationResult`, though, it might be more correct to return `ValidationResult.Success` instead of a newly created result with a null error message.  I haven't tested this.

Comment: True, `ValidationResult.Success` is much better!